# given a singly linked list, how to determine head node from a specified node in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

given a singly linked list, how to determine head node from a specified node (for e.g say node 4).total # of nodes: 10.Thanks. Logic will do,code is appreciated.

We know given a head node one can perform a forward traverse and determine next node easily.

For this case, use of doubly linked list would be simpler but i was wondering if it is possible to track down head node using singly linked list.Thanks.

Comment: A singly link list always maintains a pointer to its header node. If you simply ask the link list for the head node then it should be able to return you. It is simply not possible to track the head node from a specificed node as the links are unidirectional. What I'm wondering is how helpful would that be even if it was possible to track the header node from a given node. It will always have higher complexity than asking the linked list directly for header node. Asking the linked list for header node has a complexity of O(1).

Answer (score 3):

Its not possible at all to do that with the kind of singly linked list you've described.

Comment: It depends. The question is a bit vague. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear. But the only way this is possible is if each of your candidates is the head of a unique list, and one of them is the head that you're after.

For each candidate, traverse the list that starts from it. You will eventually hit the corresponding tail, or you will hit the node in question.

You can also make this work even if your set of candidates are not all heads of unique lists. But you would need logic to detect overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot in the singly linked list.

From Wikipedia :

> Singly linked lists contain nodes which have a data field as well as a
>   'next' field, which points to the next node in line of nodes.

You cannot go back to the previous node as you don't have any information about it. If you were given any random node of a singly linked list, the `head` of your new list will be that node, as you cannot go back any further.